# Validate alt tag should not be null using robot framework (Seleniumlibrary)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

[image]

**Scenario:**

I have a lot of `alt` tags in a web page. I am supposed to validate the `alt` tags where it should not be null or empty. It should always have some text values. How To check this in robot framework?

Attached the image FYI.

Comment: In general it's good to add the relevant bit of code as text as well even if you've added a screenshot. It helps with the readability and of course creating examples by copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all `img` elements that do not contain `alt` or has null alt using this xpath `//img[@alt='' or not(@alt)]`

If more than 1 element found, fail your test.

In robotframework code:

```
${elements without alt}=        Get Webelements         //img[@alt='' or not(@alt)]
Length Should Be    ${elements without alt}     0       msg=There are elements without the alt attribute
```